# Melt the data frame, reshape a tall data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, melt

I have the following data frame (df) and as much as I can think I am unable to wrap my head around how to do the following:

Input:

```
id  business_id type                      date1     date2     date3
1   A1          Month                     13/10/13  13/09/13  13/08/13
1   A1          Total Net Deposits        1500      951       190
1   A1          Month end Bank Balance    729       650       164
```

Expected Output:

```
id  business_id Month       Total Net Deposits  Month end Bank Balance 
1   A1          13/10/13    1500                729 
1   A1          13/09/13    951                 650
1   A1          13/09/13    190                 164
```

Comment: You mean the the first part is a data frame, but the date1, date2, date3 are 'character' columns?

Comment: return to sender. is what I would do. all the last three columns need is to be transposed by business id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a tidyr option:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  gather(date, val, date1:date3) %>% 
  spread(key = type, val = val)
#  id business_id  date    Month Month end Bank Balance Total Net Deposits
#1  1          A1 date1 13/10/13                    729               1500
#2  1          A1 date2 13/09/13                    650                951
#3  1          A1 date3 13/08/13                    164                190
#Warning:
#attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped
```

The warning occurs if your columns are stored as factors but you can ignore that.

You can do the same with `reshape2`, `data.table`, `reshape` from base R (stats) and probably some other libraries.

Comment: if you then pipe your result to `dplyr::select` you can drop the additional date column that was created. `%>% dplyr::select(-date)`. Apologies docendo, didn't mean to steal your answer, no offence intended, answer deleted.

Answer (score 4):

We could use `base R`

```
cbind(df1[1:2],setNames(as.data.frame(t(df1[-(1:3)])), df1$type))
#      id business_id    Month Total Net Deposits Month end Bank Balance
#date1  1          A1 13/10/13               1500                    729
#date2  1          A1 13/09/13                951                    650
#date3  1          A1 13/08/13                190                    164
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(reshape2)
df.m<-melt(x,id.var=c("id", "business_id","type"))
dcast(df.m,id+business_id+variable~type)
```

you can get rid of variable "variable" if you want.

```
  id business_id variable    Month MonthendBankBalance TotalNetDeposits
1  1          A1    date1 13/10/13                 729             1500
2  1          A1    date2 13/09/13                 650              951
3  1          A1    date3 13/08/13                 164              190
```

Comment: What is `library(plyr)` doing here? Also, you could make it a one - liner using `dcast(melt(df, id.var = 1:3), ... ~ type)`

Comment: somehow, I thought `dcast` came from `plyr`. thanks for the catch. good one liner..

Comment: You could add it to the answer. Its also would be better to remove `library(plyr)`, now that we on the same page. I promise a (+1) after that.